# Laravel 4.2 sending a sms to mobile phone with twilio

Tags: laravel, twilio

I am trying to send a message from my laravel app with trial but am getting an error which I cannot configure.  Any ideas?

This is my controller

```
 public function postSend() {
    if (Input::has("message")) {
        $sid = "AC792b6fee2aabbe52be63f22235b15ae5";
        $token = "3c7fb18d1a615ac3f76b0b37f13d7177";

        $http = new Services_Twilio_TinyHttp(
            'https://api.twilio.com',
            array('curlopts' => array(
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            ))
        );
        $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $http);
        $message = $client -> account -> messages -> sendMessage('+256 758 029980',
            '+256 788 207331',
            Input::get("message"));
        return Redirect::route('booking')
            ->with(
                array(
                    'success' => 'Message Send Successfully Message SID ::' . $message -> sid
                )
            );

    }
    else {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors('did not send the message');

    }
```

and the error I am getting is

```
 Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException (E_ERROR)
```

SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Answer (score 1):

What is your version of libcurl? 
On this link, (making sure you have an up to date version of the [helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php#installation)) it says that you have to Upgrade your version of libcurl: 
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions

If it does not work, you can try to Edit TinyHttp.php 
by adding: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, at $opts array 
but it's not the optimal solution.